# How can I allow user to put a mark on the damaged parts of a car in asp.net webForms?

Tags: asp.net

I want to allow the user to put marks on the damaged parts of the car, to  then save a new image. I found this solution:

```
protected void ImageMap1_Click1(object sender, ImageMapEventArgs args)
{
    int x = Cursor.Position.X;
    int y = Cursor.Position.Y;
    Bitmap bitMapIm = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Server.MapPath("~/Images/car.jpg"));
    Graphics graphicIm = Graphics.FromImage(bitMapIm);
    Pen penRed = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
    SolidBrush sp= new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
    //graphicIm.DrawString("X", new Font("Arial", 25, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Red, x, y);
     //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 200, 200);
     //graphicIm.DrawRectangle(penRed, rect);
    graphicIm.FillEllipse(sp, x, y, 25, 25);
    bitMapIm.Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images/car1.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     graphicIm.Dispose();
     bitMapIm.Dispose();
    ImageMap1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/car1.jpg";
}
```

But this saves the image as a new image every time I put a mark?

How can I make this as a simple image editor that the user put his marks and save the image at the end?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Having said that: isn't the solution to first define what "at the end" means? You put code to save into an "click" method. That just saves every time you click. Why not define some other button for example, and that simply saves when clicked?

Comment: I meant that after he finish editing the image

Comment: That is not answering my question. How do you (or your *program*) know that the user has finished his work? What if he just got up to pick a coffee? Again: without a clear way to tell you, you have NO idea when the user is DONE with his work. Besides that: the help pages clearly instruct new users to be around after asking questions. You really think it is appropriate to drop content here, to then walk away, and come back ... two weeks later?